# Why does functions in class and function have different expression when I log them in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, class

I made Example function and Example2 class.
I expected log results will be the same. But they are actually not exactly same.

```js
function Example() {}

Example.prototype.ex = function () {};
Example.iex = function () {};
console.log(Example.prototype.ex);
console.log(Example.iex);

class Example2 {
  ex() {}
  static iex() {}
}

console.log(Example2.prototype.ex);
console.log(Example2.iex);
```

The log results of code above is..

```
[Function]
[Function]
[Function: ex]
[Function: iex]
```

functions from `class` shows `[Function: name]`.
But functions from `function` shows only `[Function]` without the name of function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use *method* syntax inside a class or an object literal - that is, when the function looks like

```
functionName() {
}
```

The interpreter will automatically assign that function the name of the property. In contrast, when you have an *unnamed function expression*, like with:

```
someObj.someFn = function () {};
//               ^^^^ this function expression isn't named
```

The function does not receive a `name` property. After all, just from

```
function () {}
```

there isn't any name that could be meaningfully given to it.

(When assigned to a *standalone variable* like `const fn =`, the function will receive the name of the variable, but this does not occur when assigning to a property to an object.)

Functions with a `name` property, when logged, will show their name. Functions without a `name` property won't show their name.

```js
const obj = {};
obj.unnamedFn = function() {};
const obj2 = {
  namedFn() {}
};

console.log(obj.unnamedFn.name);
console.log(obj2.namedFn.name);
```